# How to display the friends selector dialog with PHP sdk for Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I would like show the "select friends" dialog before publish to a friend wall, like that:

[image: http://miscritscdn.brokenbulbstudios.com/game/assets/news/gifting.png]

I am not sure if it is possible with the PHP SDK, I didn't find anything about it on the Fb documentation.

Could I also use a kind of Facebook URL, such as :

```
$link=https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=<your appid>&redirect_uri=<your redirecting link>&link=<link u are posting>&message=<message>.&picture=<picture URL you want to show>&caption=<title>&description=<description>&name=<title>
```

(this on is use to post to our own wall)

**UPDATE:**

After I have selected the selected friends uids, I want add them to the Graph API link and then publish to their wall.

```
if (isset($_GET['request_ids'])) {
    $i = 0;
    $n = count(request_ids);
    while($n!=$i){
            $link = ($link + "&to=" + $request_ids[$i]);
        $i = $i +1;
    }
echo "<script language=javascript>parent.location=''</script>";
}
```

Is something wrong with my php code?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is the doc:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

You can either do that by using the JavaScript SDK, or the Graph API.

To use the graph api, you can build an URL like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests
  ?app_id=<your-app-id>
  &redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response/
  &message=Your%20message%20here
  &display=popup
```

By specifying different values for "display", you can choose how to display the selector. Can be page, popup, iframe, touch, or wap.

When the user clicks the "send request" button, gets redirected to "redirect_uri" with shome get appended (I wasn't able to find the exact name for the get parameter, but it would be easy to find out).

### UPDATE:

After the user clicks on "Send request", he gets redirected to:

```
<redirect_uri>?request_ids[0]=XXXX&request_ids[1]=YYYY&request_ids[2]=ZZZZ#_=_
```

So, in PHP, you'll find a list of ids of selected friends in `$_GET['request_ids']`. You can use that list to publish something on friends wall, by using the Graph API.

**Side note:**  must have the same domain you specified as your site URL in the app configuration page.

### UPDATE:

An improvement to your PHP code:

```
if (isset($_GET['request_ids'])) {
    for ($i=0; $i<count(request_ids); $i++){
        $link = ($link + "&to=" + $request_ids[$i]);
    }
    echo "<script language=javascript>parent.location=''</script>";
}
```

Then, what's inside `$link`?
To publish on one's wall, you should use the appropriate Graph API request, directly from the script you specified in `redirect_uri`.

Comment: Thank you for the URL, it is what I was looking for. Do you know how I can post something to the selected friends? It is posting nothing after clicked on the "Send Request" button.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the "after-button-click" thing

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use the request_ids with PHP, but I don't think I've implemented it correctly. Please see my update. Actually, I use a JS script to send the URL after an "onclick" button. Should I also use a JS function to get the request_ids?

Comment: I might be wrong but request_ids are appended like that:
`?request_ids=AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCCC...` so you need to split them by `,`

Comment: after clicking to "Send Request" button, I got this format in my URL bar: /?request=20819954259&to[0]=<id_num_0>&to[1]=<id_num_1>&to[2]=<id_num_2>&to[3]=<id_num_3>&to[4]=<id_num_4>

Comment: My previous comment was about old way of handling request_ids. Facebook recently changed request_ids format (it's described in docs) but you still can handle request_id old way, if you don't have "Requests 2.0 Efficient" enabled in your app.

Comment: I tried and for my app the destination was `?request_id[0]=...` Anyways, if for some reason the get parameter is called `to`, use `$_GET['to']`.. :)

Comment: I've tried the sample code in Fb dev website, and I got nothing from request_ids. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas333/ >> "Requests" Part

Comment: Thanks redShaow, the $_GET['to'] works. But it seems I cannot select more than one user in the url: "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=<appid>&to[0]=<id0>&to[1]=<id1>". Facebook take only the last one, <id1>. Any solution?

Comment: If no solutions, can I limit the "select friends" dialog to select only one friend?

Comment: wait, I didn't undestand what are you doing with the `$link` stuff (appending `&to=...`) plus the `echo "<script language=javascript>parent.location=''</script>";
` redirect.. You have to perform the "wall-posting" directly in the script receiving the after-submit-redirect, there's no need to redirect somewhere else..

Comment: It's what I trying to do. As I begin in Javascript and PHP, I didn't find another solution. I finally use "$facebook->api("/$uid/feed/",'post', $attachment)"; to post after the submit redirect. But it seems that the wall-posting works only for the users which have installed the application...

Comment: Is it possible to do the $_REQUEST["to"] with JavaScript?

Comment: (from the doc) you need the `publish_stream` permission in order to publish on friends wall on behalf of a given user.. What do you mean with `'do the $_REQUEST["to"] with JavaScript'`?

Comment: Hello, I am trying your solution, I need just to select one friend via open graph, then get his id and use it for publishing on his wall. The first part would be OK using your approach, but near to each user I see the icon "INVITE"...which is a bit confusing because the user is not inviting anyone. Is it possible to customize it?